# Using M2Doc programmatically : Error in the generated .docx document

Tags: java, m2doc

I'm trying to use M2Doc programmatically, I managed to generate my `.docx` file without getting errors in the validation part but I'm getting the following Error in the generated document:

```sh
{m:self.Name} Couldn't find the 'aqlFeatureAccess(org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.Hierarchical,java.lang.String)' service
```

The "self.Name" part is what I wrote in my template.

I think I'm lacking some kind of reference to a service but I don't know how to fix it.

The self variable is a reference to a model based on a meta-model I created. But I'm not sure I imported it correctly in my code.

I based my code on the code I found on the [M2Doc website](http://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/2.0.2/index.html#using-m2doc-programmatically)  + some code I found on their GitHub, especially concerning how to add a service in the queryEnvironment.

I searched in the source code of acceleo and M2Doc to see which services they add but it seems that they already import all the services I'm using.

As I said, the validation part is going well and doesn't generate a validation file.

```java
    public static void parseDocument(String templateName) throws Exception{
        final URI templateURI = URI.createFileURI("Template/"+templateName+"."+M2DocUtils.DOCX_EXTENSION_FILE);
        final IQueryEnvironment queryEnvironment = 
                org.eclipse.acceleo.query.runtime.Query.newEnvironmentWithDefaultServices(null); 
        final Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>(); // can be empty
        M2DocUtils.prepareEnvironmentServices(queryEnvironment, templateURI, options); // delegate to IServicesConfigurator

        prepareEnvironmentServicesCustom(queryEnvironment, options);

        final IClassProvider classProvider = new ClassProvider(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()); // use M2DocPlugin.getClassProvider() when running inside Eclipse
        try (DocumentTemplate template = M2DocUtils.parse(templateURI, queryEnvironment, classProvider)) {
            ValidationMessageLevel validationLevel = validateDocument(template, queryEnvironment, templateName);
            if(validationLevel == ValidationMessageLevel.OK){
                generateDocument(template, queryEnvironment, templateName, "Model/ComplexKaosModel.kaos");
            }
        }
    }
```

```java
    public static void prepareEnvironmentServicesCustom(IQueryEnvironment queryEnvironment, Map<String, String> options){

        Set<IService> services = ServiceUtils.getServices(queryEnvironment, FilterService.class);
        ServiceUtils.registerServices(queryEnvironment, services);

        M2DocUtils.getConfigurators().forEach((configurator) -> {
            ServiceUtils.registerServices(queryEnvironment, configurator.getServices(queryEnvironment, options));
        });
    }
```

```java
    public static void generateDocument(DocumentTemplate template, IQueryEnvironment queryEnvironment,
            String templateName, String modelPath)throws Exception{

        final Map<String, Object> variable = new HashMap<>();
        variable.put("self", URI.createFileURI(modelPath));
        final Monitor monitor = new BasicMonitor.Printing(System.out);
        final URI outputURI = URI.createFileURI("Generated/"+templateName+".generated."+M2DocUtils.DOCX_EXTENSION_FILE);
        M2DocUtils.generate(template, queryEnvironment, variable, outputURI, monitor);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable "self" contains an URI:

```
variable.put("self", URI.createFileURI(modelPath));
```

You have to load your model and set the value of self to an element from your model using something like:

```
final ResourceSet rs = new ResourceSetImpl();
final Resource r = rs.getResource(uri, true);
final EObject value = r.getContents()...;
variable.put("self", value);
```

You can get more details on resource loading in the [EMF documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/docs/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! This link in particular helped me a lot [Binding XML to Java](https://www.theserverside.com/news/1364302/Binding-XML-to-Java), I already followed the same steps to register my meta-model but I didn't know I needed to do it for my model too, it works well now !